# Facing problem in fetching the value of accuracy and validation accuracy on epoch ends

Tags: python, keras, neural-network, callback, resnet

I am building a model using **resnet** on **mnist** dataset. Actually I need some graphs to work on.
The complete code is [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1xJOmy2j3eqoR4hD1rIIML-wmaGcKEXQ4?usp=sharing).

The graphs that I need are,

1. **Epochs vs Validation loss**
2. **Epochs vs Training loss**
3. **Epochs vs Validation accuracy**
4. **Epochs vs Training accuracy**

I got the first two graphs. But I failed to plot the rest. The following things happen when I try to plot them.

I built a class to store the 4 values (Validation loss, Training loss, Validation accuracy, Training accuracy). The code is given below.

```
class LossHistory(Callback):
def on_train_begin(self, logs={}):
    self.losses = []
    self.val_losses = []
    self.acc = []
    self.val_acc = []
    
def on_epoch_end(self, batch, logs={}):
    self.losses.append(logs.get('loss'))
    self.val_losses.append(logs.get('val_loss'))
    self.acc.append(logs.get('acc'))
    print(logs.get('acc'))                  """ Showing "None" """
    self.val_acc.append(logs.get('val_acc'))
    print(logs.get('val_acc'))              """ Showing "None" """
```

After the completion of training...

```
predictions, history = run_resNet()
```

When I do...

```
print(history.acc)
print(history.val_acc)
```

The output I get...

```
[None, None, None, None, None,........]
[None, None, None, None, None,........]
```

What's the problem? How to get rid of it?

Comment: Does your model have the accuracy metric? Include your training code.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy the complete code has been included at the first portion of the post. [Here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1xJOmy2j3eqoR4hD1rIIML-wmaGcKEXQ4?usp=sharing#scrollTo=JVMXWWioL-rR) it is.

Comment: No, your code needs to be in the question, not as an external link.

Comment: It is possible that the metric is accuracy and not acc.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy I was trying to format my entire code to include it in the post. It is very cumbersome. I am sorry. It may take long.

Comment: That is why I just say the training code, and I also commented that the name of the metric in your logs.get call might be different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update the name for your accuracy metrics ('**accuracy**' instead of 'acc') when you try to get it from the logs as follows:

```
def on_epoch_end(self, batch, logs={}):
    self.losses.append(logs.get('loss'))
    self.val_losses.append(logs.get('val_loss'))
    self.acc.append(logs.get('accuracy'))
    print(logs.get('accuracy'))
    self.val_acc.append(logs.get('val_accuracy'))
    print(logs.get('val_accuracy'))
```

Check the updated [notebook](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1s9gOlAgY5cs9ciFPAxYMeX0Hf41SDy3j/view?usp=sharing) for complete code.

Comment: Thank you so much @Imran Rana sir. Got it.